# Book about 2 Brothers, 1 Master of Magic, the other Master of Machines

Tags: story-identification, novel, magic, robots

I read it in 1979 or thereabouts. Possibly as late as 1983. In it, the two brothers eventually wind up battling each other. My sister and I both read it but neither of us can find it in print or remember the title. Anybody know which one I'm talking about?

Comment: Do you remember any other details?

Comment: Are there robots in the story? Were they controlled by the Master of Machines? The tags say "robots" but the question text doesn't.

Comment: It sounds a lot lot Ralph Bakshi's [*Wizards,*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wizards_%28film%29) but that was an animated movie.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Roger Zelazny's [Changling](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/28807.Changeling) (published 1980) and the sequel [Madwand](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/61985.Madwand).

Pol, the infant son of a powerful wizard in a world of magic, is switched with Mark, the son of an engineer on earth. When Mark grows up to threaten his world with evil machines, Pol is brought back to oppose him.

[image]

Comment: This is quite similar to what I remember... I will accept it as the answer, and pick up a copy!

Answer (score 3):

Well I know of only one story that kinda fits this and it was the *[Brother's War](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/The_Brothers%27_War)*, a Magic the Gathering novel. However the first printing of the novel was in 1998...so likely doesn't fit the timeline. I'm unsure if the comics were even later.

> Urza and Mishra are brothers living and working in the Fallaji desert under the tutelage of their mentor Tocasia, an archaeologist. Born in the same year but on the first and last days, respectively, the brothers frequently clash but are united in their curiosity about the Thran, the ancient race that left behind the artifacts Tocasia studies. In AR 20 the brothers and Tocasia discover Koilos, the secret heart of the Thran civilization. There they find a Thran machine with a large and powerful powerstone but when Mishra and Urza reach for the stone it explodes, splitting into two halves. Urza demands to see Mishra’s half but the younger brother angrily refuses and the two have a falling out. They discover that Urza’s stone gives machines strength while Mishra’s weakens them so Urza names them the Mightstone and the Weakstone. Later on, a drunken Mishra confronts his brother and the two fight using their powerstones. Tocasia tries to intervene but when she comes between them the area explodes, killing her. Horrified, Mishra flees and the excavation site is closed....

Comment: Can you [edit] this to provide a summary of this book that includes the parts that *do* match up?